# Multiple layouts in recyclerview

Tags: android, mysql, android-recyclerview

I want to make a chat like representation where I have three layouts:
MainActivity: which I have a recyclerview
layout_sent: this is the layout for sent messages
layout_received: this is the layout for receiving messages

I am using the mySQL database: 
the query for fetching data is :

```
Select cr.user_id, cr.reply, d.griev_desc, c.user_one, c.user_two from grievance_details d , conversation_reply cr, conversation c where d.complain_id = 11 and cr.complain_id = d.complain_id and c.complain_id = 11
```

this is giving me the output :

[image]

My android adapter code is :

```
public class DifferentRowAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

String user_one;
String user_two;
ArrayList<String> user_id_array;
ArrayList<String> griev_desc_array;
ArrayList<String> reply_array_emp;
ArrayList<String> reply_array_hr;
Context c;

public DifferentRowAdapter(Context c, String user_one, String user_two,
                           ArrayList<String> user_id_array, ArrayList<String> griev_desc_array,
                           ArrayList<String> reply_array_emp, ArrayList<String> reply_array_hr) {
    this.c =c ;
    this.user_id_array = user_id_array;
    this.user_one = user_one;
    this.user_two = user_two;
    this.griev_desc_array = griev_desc_array;
    this.reply_array_emp = reply_array_emp;
    this.reply_array_hr = reply_array_hr;
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;

    System.out.println("top of for onCreateView");
    //for(String s : user_id_array)
    for(int i =0;i<user_id_array.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("in side for");
        if(user_id_array.get(i).equals(user_one)){
        //if(!s.equals(user_one)){
            //System.out.println("in side if onCreateViewHolder"+s);
            System.out.println("in side if onCreateViewHolder"+user_id_array.get(i));
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_emp_conv, parent, false);
            return new EmployeeViewHolder(view);
        }else if(user_id_array.get(i).equals(user_two)){
            //System.out.println("in side else if onCreateViewHolder"+s);
            System.out.println("in side if onCreateViewHolder"+user_id_array.get(i));
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_hr_conv, parent, false);
            return new HrViewHolder(view);
        }
        else
        {
            //System.out.println("in side else onCreateViewHolder"+s);
            System.out.println("in side if onCreateViewHolder"+user_id_array.get(i));
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    System.out.println("top of for");
    //for(String s : user_id_array)
    for(int i =0;i<user_id_array.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("in side for");
        if(user_id_array.get(i).equals(user_one)){
            System.out.println("in side if onBindViewHolder"+ user_id_array.get(i));
            //System.out.println("in side if onBindViewHolder"+s);
            //holder.employee_conversation.setText(reply_array_emp.get(position));
            ((EmployeeViewHolder)holder).employee_conversation.setText(reply_array_emp.get(position));

        }else if(user_id_array.get(i).equals(user_two)){
            //System.out.println("in side else if onBindViewHolder"+s);
            System.out.println("in side if onBindViewHolder"+user_id_array.get(i));
            ((HrViewHolder) holder).hr_conversation.setText(reply_array_hr.get(position));
        }
        else
        {
            //System.out.println("in side else onBindViewHolder"+s);
        }
    }

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return user_id_array.size();
}
```

}

but still, I am unable to inflate the two layouts as I am getting an error in :

```
((HrViewHolder) holder).hr_conversation.setText(reply_array_hr.get(position));
```

saying TypeCast not possible.

The other two Holder classes are:

```
public class HrViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView hr_conversation;

public HrViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    hr_conversation =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hr_conversation);
    System.out.println("in hrViewHolder");
}
```

}

and

```
public class EmployeeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView employee_conversation;

public EmployeeViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    employee_conversation=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.employee_conversation);
    System.out.println("in employeeViewHolder");
}
```

}

I modified the code to :

```
public class DifferentRowAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

String user_one;
String user_two;
ArrayList<String> user_id_array;
ArrayList<String> griev_desc_array;
ArrayList<String> reply_array_emp;
ArrayList<String> reply_array_hr;
Context c;

public DifferentRowAdapter(Context c, String user_one, String user_two,
                           ArrayList<String> user_id_array, ArrayList<String> griev_desc_array,
                           ArrayList<String> reply_array_emp, ArrayList<String> reply_array_hr) {
    this.c =c ;
    this.user_id_array = user_id_array;
    this.user_one = user_one;
    this.user_two = user_two;
    this.griev_desc_array = griev_desc_array;
    this.reply_array_emp = reply_array_emp;
    this.reply_array_hr = reply_array_hr;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    for(String s: user_id_array)
    {
        if(s.equals(user_one))
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(user_one);
        }
        else if(s.equals(user_two))
            return Integer.parseInt(user_two);
        else
            return 3;
    }

    return 0;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;

    System.out.println("top of for onCreateView");

    switch (viewType)
    {
        case 1 :
            System.out.println("in side case 1 onCreateViewHolder viewType     "+ viewType);
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_emp_conv, parent, false);
            return new EmployeeViewHolder(view);
        case 2:
            System.out.println("in side case 2 onCreateViewHolder viewType     "+ viewType);
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_hr_conv, parent, false);
            return new HrViewHolder(view);


    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    System.out.println("top of for");
    //for(String s : user_id_array)
    for(int i =0;i<user_id_array.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("in side for");
        if(user_id_array.get(i).equals(user_one)){
            System.out.println("in side if onBindViewHolder"+ user_id_array.get(i));
            //System.out.println("in side if onBindViewHolder"+s);
            //holder.employee_conversation.setText(reply_array_emp.get(position));
            //((EmployeeViewHolder)holder).employee_conversation.setText(reply_array_emp.get(position));

        }else if(user_id_array.get(i).equals(user_two)){
            //System.out.println("in side else if onBindViewHolder"+s);
            System.out.println("in side if onBindViewHolder"+user_id_array.get(i));
            //((HrViewHolder) holder).hr_conversation.setText(reply_array_hr.get(position));
        }
        else
        {
            //System.out.println("in side else onBindViewHolder"+s);
        }
    }

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return user_id_array.size();
}
```

}

Comment: I think you need to override getItemViewType() also in the adapter. Then based on viewtype argument in onCreateViewHolder return appropriate viewholder.

Comment: I hope this will help http://alexzh.com/tutorials/multiple-row-layouts-using-recyclerview/

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the link... but still, it's not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no need for the for loop in the array since the position of the view is passed, so you can safely modify it to the following

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(user_id_array.get(position).equals(user_one))
            return 1;
        else if(user_id_array.get(position).equals(user_two))
            return 2;
        else
            return 3;
}
```

The same applies for the `onBindViewHolder`, where you have the `ViewHolder` instance passed as a parameter, so you need to check its type at runtime to know what layout to bind to (using the `instanceof` operator).

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder instanceof EmployeeViewHolder) {
        System.out.println("in side for");
        System.out.println("in side if onBindViewHolder"+ user_id_array.get(position));
            //System.out.println("in side if onBindViewHolder"+s);
            //holder.employee_conversation.setText(reply_array_emp.get(position));
            ((EmployeeViewHolder)holder).employee_conversation.setText(reply_array_emp.get(position));

    } else if(holder instanceof HrViewHolder){
        //System.out.println("in side else if onBindViewHolder"+s);
        System.out.println("in side if onBindViewHolder"+user_id_array.get(position));
        ((HrViewHolder) holder).hr_conversation.setText(reply_array_hr.get(position));
    } else {
        //System.out.println("in side else onBindViewHolder"+s);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

override getItemViewType() in the adapter. Then based on viewtype argument in onCreateViewHolder return  viewholder.

[I hope this below link help you for multi layout in recycleview adapter :](http://gist.github.com/afollestad/c84e259e98a03134dfd5)

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestion... now the two layouts are getting inflated but in the onBindViewHolder method, 
((HrViewHolder) holder).hr_conversation.setText(reply_array_hr.get(position));
but this line is still giving me cannot be typecast error when it is getting called.

Comment: Your adapter :- 
private final int V1 = 0;private final int V2 = 1;
onCreateViewHolder:if (viewType == V1){View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.avcc, parent, false); return new MyHolder(view);}else if (viewType == V2){View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.def, parent, false);return new LoadingViewHolder(view);}onBindViewHolder: if (holder instanceof MyHolder){MyHolder Holder=(MyHolder)holder;}else if(holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder){}public int getItemViewType(int position){return jobArrayList.get(position)==null?V1:V2;}